# Slow download speeds when downloading from IIS server

Tags: windows, nginx, iis, web-server, iis-10

Hi am trying to troubleshoot "slow" files download from IIS server. I am testing locally connected to 2.5 gbit switch from my laptop.

I have two virtual machines, same hardware, one running nginx, other IIS running on server 2022. Servers are connected through 10 gbit uplinks to network.  I don't have any scanning, qos rules, etc. Just plain rule to perform test. Same testing machine, same switch port, same browser.

I generated/uploaded 40GB.zip files to both servers.

When I download from server running nginx download speed is around 230 MB per sec

When I download from server running IIS download speed is around 25 MB per sec

Is the anything I can do to make downloads faster from IIS?

Thank you.

Carlo

Comment: UPDATE: when copying from network share, from same (windows) server I get good speeds, arround 200 MB/s (same as when I download from linux and nginx)

Comment: Any malware scanning on the server? What uses CPU when downloading the file?

Comment: All normal in both scenarios. Only VM host has antivirus installed

Answer (score -1):

A Linux VM running Nginx requires significantly less resources than a VM running Windows Server 2022 with IIS installed. Keep in mind Windows Server has loads of background processes which will hog resources causing IIS to be slower (as it will be in a resource bottle neck with the background processes).

Also using Windows Server 2022 (2016 will work with IIS 10). If you NEED to have IIS 10 then use Windows Server 2016. If you can live with using IIS 8.5 use Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8.1

Comment: While I'm a big Linux fan and tend to use it for my needs, this doesn't answer the question - and I don't believe that Windows is *that* inefficient. If it was, people would be shunning it to a larger degree. I would at least expect more reasoning than pure windows bashing.

Comment: @vidarlo I am just speaking from experience of working with both Windows Server and Linux.

Comment: @vidarlo I am making the assumption that OP has made VMs with just 4gb RAM for example. In which linux would obviously be quicker than windows.